# How to make Monotouch dialog radio selector navigate back on selection?

Tags: iphone, dialog, xamarin.ios, enumeration

I'm using MonoTouch Dialog (Reflection API) to display and edit a Contact form.

One of the fields is an enumeration of the contact type and when clicked navigates to a screen with the enumeration options.

It currently works like this:

```
1) click on field type
2) navigates to screen with type options
3) select the type
4) click back to navigate to the original form
```

The way I want it to behave is:

```
1) click on field type
2) navigates to screen with type options
3) select the type
4) <strike>click back to</strike> navigate to the original form
```

(i.e. simply remove the click back step)

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you using the reflection-based API or the "traditional" API (building the element tree in code)?

Comment: Show us your working code (by editing your question). That will answer the above (and other potential) question(s) and we'll be able to tell you how best to achieve what you want :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, i'm using the Reflection API